# A deleted and migrated question is permanently stuck in Stack Overflow search results

Tags: bug, search, deleted-questions, migrated-questions

I have found a question that was erroneously posted onto Stack Overflow, migrated here to Meta, and then deleted eventually by the community, as it was a pointless duplicate.

I can find this post in [this search on the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=please%20don%27t%20downvote). For me it is the first search result:

> [Q: CAN I POST A CODE TO BE REVIEWED ON STACKOVERFLOW [migrated]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61294125/can-i-post-a-code-to-be-reviewed-on-stackoverflow?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000)
>
> network that would too be awesome. Please don't close this question If I might've broken a rule or my question might be similar to others because this might help other people to get the answer If they … I am a new contributor to StackOverflow so I quite don't know the rules here. Not too long ago, I posted an answer not according to the rules of StackOverflow so it got some downvotes. So I don't …

I assume that this will always appear in a search result, which seems to me to be undesirable. I guess that migration on the main site is not the same as deletion, and thus migrated questions can be indexed and are not skipped in the way that deleted (hidden) questions are.

Can we treat this as a search bug?

Comment: Roomba does delete locked migration stubs, even upvoted ones.

Comment: @SamuelLiew - that sounds good. So did it fail in this case? Or is there something by-design here?

Comment: It isn't 30 days yet though.

Comment: Ah, I need to wait 30 days! Gotcha, thanks.

Comment: Roomba's bouncing around the chair legs.

Comment: @marcellothearcane: the Roomba ran out of battery and has made its way back to the base station for a nice drink. Back in six days for another clean-up!

Comment: *"I have found a question that was erroneously posted onto Stack Overflow, migrated here to Meta, and then deleted eventually by the community, as it was a pointless duplicate."* The real trick, halfer, is finding a post that was erroneous posted onto Stack Overflow, migrated here to Meta, and then *not* deleted because it was *not* a pointless duplicate. I'll wait. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: ... by which time they will have invented a floating Roomba that can take cobwebs off the ceiling `:=)`