# Some deleted posts show up in search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

In 2016 this question was asked:

[Custom search incorrectly returns deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335639/custom-search-incorrectly-returns-deleted-questions)

and in the comments Oded in his capacity as SE developer re-assured the issue would resolve itself after an re-index of Elastic.

I know that it is not 6 to 8 years later but I assume that re-index did take place in the mean time.

Today user [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) asked in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50217103#50217103) if finding deleted answers was a feature. After blaming caching and that being ruled out I confirmed that this search

> [`Winercounter`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Winercounter&mixed=0)

does return a deleted post and that was confirmed by [Scratte](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50217231) and [Alon Eitan](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50217185#50217185)

Could it be that the index is up for a re-index again? Or is there another reason this particular post got stuck in there, a bit similar to [A deleted and migrated question is permanently stuck in Stack Overflow search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397399/a-deleted-and-migrated-question-is-permanently-stuck-in-stack-overflow-search-re)

I find it hard to search for other occurrences of deleted posts that are stuck in the index. I tried a couple of my own deleted answers but the few I checked didn't turn-up in search results so it is not that all deleted posts are now searchable. But what the condition is under which they are returned is unclear to me. I have too few data points.

Can this be looked at and if it is part of a broader problem and easily fixed be repaired?

Comment: I’m guessing that something went wrong with updating that post in the index when it was deleted. I’ve re-deleted it and it should disappear from search in a few minutes time.

Comment: As for “broader problem” issues: there may well be posts in the index with incorrect status info; there are millions of posts and indexing can and will sometimes go out of sync in places. It would require a full re-index to find all such posts and a reindex could reintroduce errors elsewhere at the same time. A full re-index of SO would take a significant amount of time...

Comment: Aaand the index has been updated. Your example is no longer returned. As a moderator I can still find it but I have to explicitly include deleted posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What would be the recommended course of action if we find more in the future? Mod-flag? Post on Meta again?

Comment: @Dharman we may need to wait for dev confirmation that my diagnosis is correct. Of so, a mod-flag would be plenty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is probably a relatively rare event. I've undeleted then re-deleted the post and the index has been updated.

All posts, deleted or not, are indexed into the search engine. The search engine is a separate component with its own data store, separate from the database, and as posts are created, edited, voted on and deleted, etc. the search engine is meant to pick up those changes, in batches, and this is why there is often a bit of a delay between changes to posts and the search engine reflecting this. Deleted posts are included because 10k+ users can search for their own deleted posts with the [`deleted:` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), and moderators can find *any* deleted post this way.

And because the search engine is separate, sometimes that process of updating can break. It doesn't happen often, and when it does I expect it to be both rare and limited in scope. The site has 10s of millions of posts, and the number of events that require a re-index of a post run in the 100 millions (if not in the billions already), so *some* discrepancies are to be expected. I think the fact that this post was not registered as deleted was such an update failure. A Stack Overflow developer would have to confirm this, of course.

In future, if you find another such a post, feel free to flag it for moderator attention, and we'll just cycle it through undeletion and deletion to force another re-index.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a one off. It continues to happen.

Comment: @Braiam: it happens. It's a busy site, there are a metric tone of deltas being processed by the search engine, things get dropped sometimes.

Comment: The thing is that this "sometimes" had enough time for [cache invalidation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417769/792066) to happen, if it ever happens.

Answer (score 18):

We deployed a fix today that addresses the root cause of this bug.

### Background

We run scheduled routines weekly that clean up posts that fit a variety of criteria (lovingly nicknamed [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)). Over time, the volume of posts that are deleted by this process weekly has been steadily increasing, meaning the time it takes to run this process has also been increasing.

We also regularly (every 1 minute on Stack Overflow) run refreshes of our Elasticsearch engine to update posts that have had state changes (edits, deletions, etc). This engine is what powers search across the network.

We hit a threshold in the last few years where we regularly refresh Elasticsearch, WHILE also mass-deleting posts via Roomba. In there lies a timing issue, where the Elastic refresh mechanism would miss posts that were actively being deleted, leading the cached post to be out-of-sync with our database and therefore able to be searched by any user.

### The fix

We now perform targeted refreshes of the cached Elastic posts immediately after deleting them, ensuring that each one stays in sync with the post in our database.

### Clean up

This bug has been around for some time, meaning there are likely quite a few posts that are still out-of-sync between SQL Server and Elastic. We will be planning a maintenance window to perform a full rebuild of our Elastic search indexes that have been affected, which will retroactively fix any problem posts.

Comment: Will this also affect posts that were visible after being deleted in another way? (There used to be some spam posts that were showing up but they eventually were handled by moderators.)

Comment: @Laurel I'm not super-familiar with our spam deletion process but I can follow-up to see if that would either be addressed by this or needs a similar fix applied.

Comment: Let me know if you want links to the spam posts. They're all in my flag history on June 28th.

Comment: The fix has [since regressed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421703/6296561)

Answer (score 5):

More examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/70729254 (deleted 2022-02-19, found in search 2022-08-17)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/71772014 (deleted 2022-05-21, found in search 2022-08-17)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/68049314 (deleted 2022-05-21, found in search 2022-08-17)

Comment: Are there particular search terms that are prone to this?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Another user took a closer look after I remarked that it was interesting that two were deleted on the same day, and [it appears that some (large) batches of deleted posts aren't getting removed from search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419881/208273).