# Why is this question that was deleted by the Community user not deleted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, community-user

While browsing the [annotated posts](https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts) list on Stack Overflow, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57888986/11171084) which is currently locked and occasionally serving as a Triage audit.

The thing is, in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57888986/timeline), there's a [deletion event](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57888986/timeline#history_6bd5ee26-9400-4fb2-8131-9f7f24e12c44) that indicates that the post was deleted by the Community user. It was simultaneously locked, which signals to me that it was red-flag-deleted.

But it's *still visible* to me (a <10k user). There are no timeline events indicating that it was undeleted by a moderator or the Community user. I was [told by a moderator](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8903951#8903951) that there *is* a red-flag-deleted answer on the question which I (correctly) can't see, so I'm left wondering why this question isn't actually deleted given that it looks like it was given the same treatment.

There's also no migration history visible to me, so I don't think this has anything to do with wild migration weirdness.

This isn't a one-off issue. Here's a [second instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743589/how-to-integrate-sonarqube-with-azure-directory-service-what-are-the-important) ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58743589/timeline)) that exhibits the problem. For a more recent example of this occurring, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813226). For <10k users, here's a [screenshot of the timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOtZG.png) where you can definitively see two deletion events with no undeletion event between them.

---

All linked instances of this issue have since been spam flagged by moderators and are now *actually* deleted. This still leaves the question of why these posts weren't deleted correctly by the Community user in the first place, though. It also does appear to be a still ongoing, although quite rare, issue.

Comment: Can't say whether it's important, but the timeline indicates that the Delete and Lock were [*simultaneous* events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TWQn.png), rather than performed one after the other. I've never seen [that notation on a timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sHk3.png) before (*S*'s appear on hover).

Comment: I grabbed a deleted spam question from MSE and looked at the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/366319/timeline), and that "Simultaneous" notation apparently *does* happen for [spam/rude flag deleted posts](https://i.imgur.com/OLN12K8.png). @zcoop98

Comment: @zcoop98 This is the case with any red-flag-deletion. The post is deleted and immediately locked by the Community user and hovering on the date of either of the events shows that "S". Pretty normal. What's not normal is that the post is not actually deleted.

Comment: The events are in the correct order in posthistory: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1420946  There also was a spam flag on that question (2nd result set in above query)

Comment: Maybe someone can correct me but something else is strange. If the post is deleted **by Community ♦** because of a red flag, shouldn't it have at least 6 downvotes? Both the question and answer only have one downvote.

Comment: @41686d6564 If a moderator submitted their spam flag, it would only really need to be a -1 (their spam flags invoke the related penalties/deletion events immediately). But, if it happened to have an upvote, it would be at 0 total. Could you use your >1k powers to see what the vote counts are by clicking the score?

Comment: @Spevacus You are correct, it has a score of +1/-1, meaning it was deleted by a mod with a spam flag.

Comment: @Spevacus The votes on both the question and answer are +1/-1 but, AFAIK, if a mod submits their spam flag, it should show that it was deleted by that mod, not by Community ♦. I could be wrong though. Edit: [here's an example of a red-flagged post deleted by a mod](https://i.imgur.com/LSGSlWL.png). Perhaps that's a different action though.

Comment: Both at +1 and -1. But if a mod submitted their spam flag, then I expect to see the mods name there, not Community. But I don't know what happens when someone flags as spam and the mod "accepts" that flag during review.

Comment: Per the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/622284), one mod-cast red flag invokes the same effects as six normal-user red flags, which if my experience on Meta SE serves me well, will invoke the Community user to do all the deletion/locking work for them just like if it got 6 normal-user-cast red flags.

Comment: @10Rep Except the +1 was on September 12th and the -1 was on September 18th. It had another upvote from the 12th, which I suspect went away on January 11th 2020.

Comment: I don't know why it wasn't deleted, so I'm not answering. Up to the point where the audits start, the timeline looks like any other post which was deleted via a moderator spam flag (i.e. there isn't an indication why it wasn't actually deleted). However, it was supposed to have been deleted as a result of a moderator spam flag from another moderator. I've unlocked it and re-applied a spam flag, which has re-locked it and re-deleted it.

Comment: Same thing's happened with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813226) one, so... why is this still happening?

Comment: Just to point out the obvious: One thing that all three examples here presented have in common is that they were used as audits in Triage.

Comment: @AdrianMole Is that significant?  Do you think this might be intentional, for the Triage queue only?

Comment: @Ollie No idea. The subtle mechanics of how review audits work (or don't work) are beyond my comprehension. But I have a vague notion that Triage may work a bit differently than the other, more established queues.

Comment: I'm moving this back to status-review for someone to take a look, given that it was declined on the basis that it wasn't still happening (with a request for reports if it's still happening), but evidence has since shown that it continues to happen.  Of course, staff should feel free to re-decline it if they so choose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We rebuilt our Elastic search index today and cleaned up all the incorrect data for existing, deleted posts that were still appearing in the search results.

The root cause of the issue was addressed already, so it will not happen for future post deletions.

You can find a precise description of the issue and the fix [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420161/19635424).

Answer (score 4):

I looked into this a bit.

Yes, this seems to have happened a few times, but not seeing examples more recent than 2019. Can't find it happening with a greater frequency, or more recent (leave a comment if you can show otherwise). So if that is the case, we'll leave this as-is, and chalk it up to some weirdness with the deletion at that time and/or audits.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68813226/208273), linked in the comments on the question, is from 2021-08-17.

Comment: [Example from 2021-12-20](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69644904/3773011). This does appear to be happening periodically. While it's not the same issue, [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416302/community-deleted-roombad-questions-are-sometimes-still-showing-counting-in-the) appears to at least also be in the Community deletion code. The specific question which I've linked here doesn't appear to be causing all that much harm by not being deleted, so I'm going to leave it that way for a while in case you want to take a look at it.

Comment: [Another example](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55078134#55078134) from just now.