# Community-deleted/Roomba'd questions are sometimes still showing/counting in the questions page for a given tag

Tags: bug, search, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

While participating in the burnination of [downloadfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile), I took a look at all remaining questions at one point, and was returned with the following result when searching using the query `[downloadfile] closed:no`:

[image: List of remaining questions with [downloadfile] tagged that are not closed and--ostensibly--not deleted, either]

The two questions in the screenshot which are currently at a score of -1, to my surprise, were both deleted by Community 9 days earlier! So why are they showing up for me, a non-moderator?

This is the URL for the query: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdownloadfile%5D+closed%3Ano&searchOn=3

And these are the two questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513623/jsf-jasperreport-open-download-file-in-browser and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002599/how-to-submit-the-file-from-html-form-to-a-web-server-in-c

---

<sub>Note: Catija and others (moderators and non-moderators) were able to reproduce this in a private chatroom, so she/they may be able to provide additional information to devs if needed.</sub>

<sub>Note 2: I encountered a similar issue recently with another tag where there were no results shown, but still results listed in the "`n` results" count at the top. When Makyen undeleted and re-deleted those manually, they dropped off the list and it started showing "no results" as expected for me... which is why we suspect this might be an issue with automatic, Community-deleted posts, specifically.</sub>

Comment: Even repro for <10k users who can't see deleted posts. Indeed even when signed out.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine This makes sense; if the results aren't filtered out as `deleted` when the search results list is created and populated, then anyone should be able to see them.

Comment: shouldiblamecaching.com seems to have the answer.

Comment: @Braiam Not really; this is an issue that persists for over a week. Caching shouldn't be an issue on the client or even server side over that long of a period.

Comment: I saw this last week when I did a search on different tags as well.  This MSO post seems related: [Some deleted posts show up in search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400332/some-deleted-posts-show-up-in-search-results).  I was planning to follow the advise there and flag one of the deleted questions, but maybe the issue is not just a "one-off".

Comment: @toolic I don't like that advice from Martijn particularly; not as a user, and certainly I wouldn't like it as a developer. There is a noticeable pattern here of questions which are _Community-deleted_ not getting picked up. Granted, my current sample size of ~5 over the last couple of weeks is hardly even a drop in the bucket for the total number of questions on the site, but the fact they all have that Community deletion in common indicates something else... the post in the question you link also happens to be a user-deleted answer, not a Community-deleted question.

Comment: @toolic at any rate, I am posting this at the request of Catija, so even if a mod could quickly undelete and re-delete (which Makyen has done for some others I found earlier), the bug report hopefully will be useful for the dev team to take a look at :-)

Comment: @TylerH: I agree with you that this is a problem.  I don't like that advice either, but it was the most relevant thing I found when I did a search last week.

Comment: I've manually deleted them again, as per [my previous answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400332/some-deleted-posts-show-up-in-search-results) and they'll be gone from the index soon.

Comment: @catija heads-up, I marked this as a duplicate, as this is not the first time this has been reported.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you know how long it takes for the re-index to complete (e.g. more than 3 hours)? I'm showing "1" at the top of the questions page for [tag:downloadfile] even though no questions are showing up in the list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8AoY.png

Comment: @TylerH: the tag page question count value is cached. I don't know how long it takes to update, but it'll update. A lot of tag-related stuff is cached for a full 24 hours, so it could be it stays like that until tomorrow.