# Many posts deleted during roomba operation show up in search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

This is an extension/supplement of the issue reported in [Some deleted posts show up in search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400332/15497888)

I happened across a search earlier today which happened to contain several of these posts. When the posts were re-deleted, [Ryan mentioned](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55082367) that it was interesting that two of the posts were removed on the same day. It turns out that they were not just removed on the same day, they were removed within the same *second*. I put together a very simple [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1628236) which finds all the posts that were deleted during that roomba batch.

This is a very tedious thing to check. The text from deleted posts is not accessible through the SEDE or through the API so validating that these posts are discoverable via search is a *very* manual process.

That said for a *very* small sample of just 400 questions (~4% of the total [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1628236) results), I found that ***67*** posts are *still* accessible via search. Note it is possible that this is an *under representative sample* in that I could have missed some posts during my search.

Here are the results and corresponding search links for 400 of the questions in the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1628236) (The first 200 in the dataset + an additional 200 randomly sampled from the rest of the dataset):

|  | Post Link | Search Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [9110764](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9110764) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22can+we+change+slide+movement+from+vertical+to+horizontal+slide+movement+instead+of+vertical+within+slides+in+slide+deck%3F%0Alike+2nd+slide+in+this+site%22&searchOn=3) |
| 2 | [11256957](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11256957) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+using+OBOUT+Controls+in+my+web+application%2C+in+that+I+need+to+search+from+drop+down+data+when+I+type+any+keyword+it+should+search+from+drop+drown.+Obout+works+fine+untill+page+post+back+but+when+page+is+post+back%22&searchOn=3) |
| 3 | [13102451](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102451) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+need+launch+visual+studio+new+project+dialog+from+within+my+vspackage.+And+i+can%27t+find+info+about+how+i+can+do+this+yet.+So+my+question+is+-+how%3F+And+generally+this+question+is+not+only+about+%22new+project+dialog%22%22&searchOn=3) |
| 4 | [14075273](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14075273) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22however+I+would+like+to+understand+what+is+wrong+with+my+query%2C+db+or+annotation+that+generate+duplication.%22) |
| 5 | [14114904](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14114904) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27m+using+Delphi+XE3.%0AI%27m+asking+my+self+if+I+can%2C+with+Windows+messages%2C+do+a+dran-n-drop+from+my+application+to+Windows+explorer+some+files.+I%27ve+done+the+thing+from+explorer+to+my+application%2C+it%27s%22&searchOn=3) |
| 6 | [14720045](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14720045) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%0Ai+have+an+C+toolkit+which+I+would+like+to+use+in+a+program+I+wrote+in+java.+What+is+the+easiest+way+I+can+do+this+with+losing+the+basic+functionality+of+the+toolkit.+The+basic+function+of+this+web+service+is+to+input+data%22&searchOn=3) |
| 7 | [15160476](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15160476) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22So+I%27m+looking+for+a+way+of+having+this+fixed+div+always+appear+on+top+of+my+page+content+regardless+of+relatively+positioned+elements%2C+is+there+any+easy+way+of+achieving+this+short+of+making+the+relatively+positioned%22&searchOn=3) |
| 8 | [16911435](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16911435) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+using+python+2.7+video+capture+package.It+gives+following+error+when+i+try+to+instantiate+the+Device.%0AError%3A+Capture+Graph+could+not+be+created.Here+is+my+code.+I+am+using%22&searchOn=3) |
| 9 | [16911684](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16911684) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Edit+for+solve+part+of%22&searchOn=3) |
| 10 | [16920865](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16920865) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27m+trying+to+load+various+unloaded+icons+from+the+sencha+touch+framework.%22&searchOn=3) |
| 11 | [16938666](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16938666) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22After+that+i+restarted+my+phpmyadmin+and+found+that+these+variable+values+has+not+be%22&searchOn=3) |
| 12 | [16951258](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16951258) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+seen+some+similar+questions+but+none+was+able+to+help+me+so+thats+why+i+am+posting+this+with+my+code+as+i+am+unable+to+troubleshoot+where+the+problem%22&searchOn=3) |
| 13 | [16956561](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956561) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22How+can+i+show+the+image+which+is+on+ftp+server+without+downloading+it+%3F+%26+just+using+the+URL%22&searchOn=3) |
| 14 | [16964680](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16964680) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22In+my+application+I+am+implementing+android+notification+using+alarm+manager+to+get+notification+on+specific+time.+I+am+successfully+getting+notification+on+same+time+but+problem+is+that+when+my+app+is+in+background%28by%22&searchOn=3) |
| 15 | [16967751](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16967751) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+a+java+stand-alone+application+that+runs+embedded+tomcat6+to+publish+some+webapps+that+use+objects+of+the+stand-alone+app+to+get+the+html%22&searchOn=3) |
| 16 | [16968742](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16968742) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27ve+been+trying+to+learn+associations+and+specifically+hasMany+through+because%2C+according+to+cakephp+docs%2C+that%27s+what+will+be+best+for+my%22&searchOn=3) |
| 17 | [16977971](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16977971) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22so+I+want+to+do+something+a+bit+different+than+you+usually+see+with+Android+code%2C+but+I+don%27t+know+where+to+start.%22&searchOn=3) |
| 18 | [16979861](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16979861) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22met+with+another+problem+in+playing+with%22&searchOn=3) |
| 19 | [16980684](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16980684) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27m+pretty+new+to+WPF+with+Prism+and+really+new+to+the+MVVM+Pattern.%22&searchOn=3) |
| 20 | [16982463](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16982463) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+a+json+answer%2C+here+is+my%22&searchOn=3) |
| 21 | [16984832](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16984832) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Now+whenever+i+make+a+set+or+get+for+item+in+my+second+Class+it+affect+the+items+list+in+my+first+class+usually+in+ios+i+make+a+copy+so+i+wont+have+any+problem+please+help+me+to+solve+this+issue+thanks.%22&searchOn=3) |
| 22 | [16986446](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16986446) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+coded+it+in+ColdFusion+but+someone+can+help+me+on+seeing+my+http+request+whether+I+have+correctly+placed+the+things+in+correct+attributes+and+the+way+of+sending%22&searchOn=3) |
| 23 | [16986909](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16986909) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Hello+I+am+working+in+a+project+in+wich+you+are+supposed+to+open+some+%22+chat-windows%22%2C+this+windows+use+a+plugin+for+a+custom+scroll+bar.+I+am+accessing++JSON+to+get+the+variables+of+the+name+of+the+person+and+his%22&searchOn=3) |
| 24 | [16993507](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16993507) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+a+WPF+application+with+treeview+control.+When+I+implement+this+method+to+parse+the+strings+I+can+find+a%22&searchOn=3) |
| 25 | [17018354](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17018354) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+trying+to+integrate+alfresco+4.2+CE+with+Office+2010+but+i+am+not+able+to+see+any+%22Edit+Inline%22+option+in+alfresco+share+as+well+as+i+am+getting+below+errors.%22&searchOn=3) |
| 26 | [17021039](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17021039) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+want+to+share+an+image+to+Facebook+and+I+am+using+this%22&searchOn=3) |
| 27 | [17022602](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17022602) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+want+to+use+the+native+selectfield+on+the+iPhone+not+the+custom+Sencha+Touch+2%22&searchOn=3) |
| 28 | [17028397](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17028397) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Ok+I+looked+this+up+countless+times.+Many+people+said+in+order+to+use+imagecreatefrompng%28%27some+sort+of+photobucket+url+or+imgur.com%27%29%2C+you+need+to+do+this%22&searchOn=3) |
| 29 | [17029482](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17029482) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+JSON+response+working+but+cannot+get+it+to+work+cross-domain.+If+anyone+can+help+me+get+this+code+working+I+would+be+deeply+grateful.+Here+is+the+working+page%2C+using+the+code%22&searchOn=3) |
| 30 | [17030900](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17030900) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27m+developing+a+VB.NET+application+that+will+be+run+also+on+mobile%22&searchOn=3) |
| 31 | [17042874](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17042874) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+the+following+for+loop+code%22&searchOn=3) |
| 32 | [17046026](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17046026) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27m+trying+to+import+more+than+14.000+mini-tables+%28which+together+make+a+big+unique+table%29+on+SQL+Server.+This+explains+why+I+can%27t+use+the+wizard+to+do+it%2C+so+I%27m+trying+to+do+it+by%22&searchOn=3) |
| 33 | [17052763](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17052763) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+the+following+LINQ+query+that+I+would+like+to+return+several+grouped+fields+along+with+a+count+summary.+I+get+the+correct+grouping+and+count+but+I%27m+not+sure+of+the+syntax+to+return++each+field+I+need+from%22&searchOn=3) |
| 34 | [17063184](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17063184) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+trying+to+parse+my+tweets+into+clickable+links+for+mentions%2C+hashtags+and+links.+The+hashtags+and+links+are+working.+But+there+is+something+wrong+with+my+mentions+part...%22&searchOn=3) |
| 35 | [17071663](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071663) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+created+an+xml+file+with+QT+%28QXmlStreamWriter%29+and+I+want+to+add+at+the+end+of+the+file+a+node+that+contains+some%22&searchOn=3) |
| 36 | [17368904](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17368904) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+a+bunch+of+open+source+libraries+which+use+signal.h+and+the+siginfo+struct+from+it.+Unfortunately+I+got+a+new+desktop+and+I+needed+a+kernel+update+to+3.8+%28from+3.7%29+to+fix+some+issues+with+my+hardware+%28went+from%22&searchOn=3) |
| 37 | [18475275](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18475275) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+use+Cakephp+Framework+for+my+project+and+I+have+a+problem+for+entities+model+.%22&searchOn=3) |
| 38 | [18674647](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18674647) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+wish+I+could+rename+a+process+while+it+runs+with+the+following%22&searchOn=3) |
| 39 | [18827181](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18827181) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27m+working+on+an+AIR+app+and+I%27ve+run+itno+one+problem%2C+hope+some+of+you+can+help%22&searchOn=3) |
| 40 | [18951175](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18951175) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27m+trying+to+code+a+weighted+Holm%27s+procedure+in+R+among+other+things.+I+also+want+to+add+alpha+and+keep+a+total+count+on+how+much+alpha+is+being+used.+The+final+total+of+this+count+%28WHalphaTOTAL%29+is+what+I%27m%22&searchOn=3) |
| 41 | [19210253](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19210253) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%27ve+upgraded+the+PHP+running+on+our+box+to+PHP5.5+and+am+looking+into+leveraging+the+new+password+hashing+framework.+Through+benchmarking+I%27ve+decided+to+use+a+cost+of+11+instead+of+the+default+10.+Is+there+anyway+to%22&searchOn=3) |
| 42 | [19457262](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19457262) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+trying+to+create+a+dynamic+connection+string+for+my+POCO+EF5+Web+App%2C+and+having+some+problem.%22&searchOn=3) |
| 43 | [19475445](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19475445) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22This+is+the+error+I+get+when+I+run+a+simple+lex+program+in+the+form+of+%25%25+.+The+same+program+is+running+fine+else%22&searchOn=3) |
| 44 | [19497168](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19497168) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22After+2%2B+days+of+trying+to+figure+out+how+to+make+it+work%2C+I%27m+gonna+ask+for+help+now.+This+is+just+a+simple+app+just+to+get+Google+Cloud+Endpoints+to+work.+It+deploys+fine+but+is+actually+not+working.+It%27s+hard+to%22&searchOn=3) |
| 45 | [19564405](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19564405) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Here%27s+the+error+log+and+my%22&searchOn=3) |
| 46 | [19587848](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19587848) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+infinity+and+jquery+1.9.1+I+try+to+implementation+like+this%22&searchOn=3) |
| 47 | [19617864](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19617864) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+was+trying+to+create+a+simple+css+sprite+animation.+Something+similar+to+example%22&searchOn=3) |
| 48 | [19620079](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19620079) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+a+link_to_function+in+rails+view+to+render+partials+dynamically.+But+I%27m+not+able+to+set+the+%3Adisabled+attribute+to+the%22&searchOn=3) |
| 49 | [19645092](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19645092) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+trying+to+implement+an+AJAX+partial+update+in+my+page%2C+my+codes+are+as%22&searchOn=3) |
| 50 | [19656389](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19656389) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Hello+I+have+a+little+problem+with+displaying+the+custom+design+provided+by+the+iCheck+JS+library.+The+following+code+works+fine+on+static+html+pages.+However+when+I+import+everything+into+my+asp.net+project+I+am+not+able+to%22&searchOn=3) |
| 51 | [19714208](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19714208) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+creating+a+survey.+I+want+the+form+to+submit+via+ajax+if+someone+clicks+a+radio+button+%28specifically%2C+%27rating+4%27+or+%27rating+5%27.+If+they+click+anything+else%2C+I+want+it+to+bring+in+the+div+%23getMore+and%22&searchOn=3) |
| 52 | [19798042](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19798042) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+trying+to+insert+data.+I+am+inserting+a+new+Company+that+has+a+new+branch+that+has+a+new+Company+Contact.+Firstly+the+schema.+Notice+the+Many+to+Many+relationship+between+CompanyBranch+and+CompanyContact.+My+issue+is%22&searchOn=3) |
| 53 | [19805141](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19805141) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22i+have+multiple+dates+in+the+remote+database+i+get+those+dates+and+in+JSON+and+send+the+date+to+calendar+to+highlight%22&searchOn=3) |
| 54 | [19811138](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19811138) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+want+to+implement+custom+Google+search+in+a+site+which+made+in+cakephp%22&searchOn=3) |
| 55 | [20008427](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20008427) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22My+full+target+is+to+make+a+Chrome+extension+which+let+me+to+open+a+contextual+menu+on+any+Wikipedia+table+to+get+its+values+for+my+needs.+I+learnt+by+my+self+that+this+project+is+too+big+for+me%2C+one+who+never+seen+web%22&searchOn=3) |
| 56 | [20671079](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20671079) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22It+seems+like+there+is+something+within+the+system+that+has+that+.dll+code+locked.+I+suspect%2C+that+if+i+gave+it+a+new+name%2C+that+my+problem+will+be+bypassed%2C+but+it+doesn%27t+fix+%22THE%22+problem.%22&searchOn=3) |
| 57 | [20694670](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20694670) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22PS+Newbee+here.++I+am+writing+up+some+PS+2.0+functions+to+manage+config+files.++In+some+cases%2C+I+just+need+to+verify+that+a+node%27s+attribute+exists%2C+and+then+add+it+if+it%27s+not+found.++At+other+times%2C+I+have+to%22&searchOn=3) |
| 58 | [21042597](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21042597) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+to+create+a+graph+who+represents+how+some+customers+are+connected+to+3+stores+of+a%22&searchOn=3) |
| 59 | [34565311](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34565311) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+using+OpenStreetMap+for+showing+the+Route+Path+between+me+and+The+User.+Is+it+possible+to+draw+a+route+path+between+two+Geo+Points+in%22&searchOn=3) |
| 60 | [71870701](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71870701) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22When+opening+menu%2C+cursor+is+moved+over+a+button.+How+can+this+interaction+be+coded+in+Cypress+studio%3F+I+tried+like+this%2C+but+it+does+not%22&searchOn=3) |
| 61 | [71884261](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71884261) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Can+someone+help+with+this+WKUserScript+for+Apple+Pay+in%22&searchOn=3) |
| 62 | [71893832](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71893832) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22For+example%2C+in+a+gaming+app%2C+a+server+needs+to+confirm+that+the+gaming+data+that+it+is+receiving+is+actually+generated+by+the+mobile+app.+This+should+be+possible%2C+because+if+it+is+not%2C+users+should+be+able+to+send%22&searchOn=3) |
| 63 | [71895840](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71895840) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22here+I+have+used+fontawesomefx+to+create+javafx+application+using+scene+builder.+but+i+can%27t+rung+this+using+intelij+ide.+why+is+it%3F+how+I+solve+that%22&searchOn=3) |
| 64 | [71902304](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71902304) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+a+number+variable+inside+a+list+of+object%22&searchOn=3) |
| 65 | [71907310](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71907310) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22It+seems+the+timeout+option+does+not+work+when+running+a+script+in+the+background+with%22&searchOn=3) |
| 66 | [71908915](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71908915) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+plan+to+make+a+program+to+detect+people+into+a+white+pixel+in+the+classroom%2C+then+I+will+divide+the+white+pixel+by+the+area+of+interest+so+that+I+get+the+density+of+the+crowd+in+the+room.+This+is+the%22&searchOn=3) |
| 67 | [71914000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71914000) | [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22When+I+want+to+do+simple+file+manipulations%2C+like+renaming+files%2C+editing+txt+files+via+code+etc.%2C+I+currently+to+this+via+ExtendScript+and+InDesign+as+target+application.+Is+there+a+plugin+that+lets+me+do+this%2C+so+I%22&searchOn=3) |

To be clear, there were **9961** questions deleted in this singular roomba operation. Assuming a uniform ~16.75% (67 / 400) failure rate<sup>1</sup> on just this singular operation there are ~1668 questions in *just this batch* which are still accessible via search.

The [previous advice given by Martijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400367/15497888) was to flag for moderator attention when these are found. However, this was predicated on this being "a relatively rare event," however, it appears it is not a rare event<sup>2</sup> and flagging thousands of posts is not feasible or a reasonable use of anyone's time.

So I am once again asking: can this be looked into?

---

<sup>1</sup> It may not be safe to assume that all posts fail at the same rate. (*e.g.* even in this small sample there appears to be a higher failure rate on older posts)

<sup>2</sup> While there is supporting evidence throughout MSO that there exist other roomba deleted posts which are still accessible via search, it does not necessarily mean that all roomba operations have similar failure rates.

Comment: I'm going to refrain from manually fixing these, as 1) it may be useful to have a list for staff investigation, and 2) there's way too many and fixing a handful of them is a drop in the bucket anyway.

Comment: It's also interesting that when they appear in search results, there's no indication that the post is deleted until you actually open it. Normally, deleted posts have a pink/red-ish background and the (newly added) "Deleted" label in front of the title.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that all 39 questions listed above were created between 2012 and 2013. This could be relevant.

Comment: @41686d6564 my guess would be that that's related to how they were queried via SEDE, rather than anything meaningful.  [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419880/208273) has a couple from that date created in 2021 and 2022.

Comment: Ryan is correct; The query is sorted by post id so the first 100 posts that I searched are guaranteed to be the oldest posts.

Comment: Should I add links here to posts that weren't properly deleted with a spam flag? I flagged 6 on June 28 and most of those were from the [Oceanbase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418569/6083675) tag (which considering it only had 40 questions in it means that it's really not uncommon and could even be triggered by the way posts are being handled). These posts were actually easy to find when they were still live since it's not very common to have low scoring locked posts.

Comment: @Laurel Those are probably related, but are a bit different. Currently, there's "[Why is this question that was deleted by the Community user not deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408326/3773011)" which covers the situation where the post doesn't actually get deleted by the Community user upon there being 6 red flags (i.e. Community locks it, but fails to actually delete), as opposed to is actually deleted while still visible in search. Please either create a Community Wiki answer there, and/or add them as comments to Yaakov's answer, which is what we've been doing from time to time.

Comment: Hold on, apparently these posts being picked up just now by the Roomba are *up to ten years old*? In at least one case, with no activity in the interim whatsoever that I can detect? Oh, I think I misunderstood; the Roomba operated on a normal schedule, but we only noticed now that the search can still pick up Roomba-deleted questions?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel from what I understand the questions weren't eligible to be deleted automatically yet, for example the 2nd question in the list had a score of 1, probably the user who posted that got deleted recently making the question eligible to be deleted ("_has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner_"). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Comment: A thought I just had: if deletions aren't being consistently propagated into search, what else isn't being propagated there?  Are there posts that don't appear in search at all?  Edits (or worse, redactions) that aren't taking effect there?

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate of [Some deleted posts show up in search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400332/some-deleted-posts-show-up-in-search-results) because that one received [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420161/8967612) that's applicable to this question too.