# I can search for deleted questions... kinda?

Tags: bug, search

The following [query gives me 3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bterm%5D+is%3Alocked&searchOn=3) as results. All three are deleted at least 7 days ago. It seems a caching problem, but it confuses since the search engine is used to find how many stuff there is, if any. Do the search engine needs a kick? This seems to only happen after the index rebuild.

Comment: I re-deleted them and now they are gone from the index again.