# Issue in Search filters: "deleted:no" sets "only content you own ..."

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, filtering

**Current behavior**

If I add "deleted:no" to a search query (in order to filter out deleted questions), the search results start with the following notice :

> Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content

and only items posted by me appear.

**Expected behavior**

When using "deleted:no", the scope of the query should still be global.

The "only your own content" filter should be turned on only for if "deleted" is set to "yes"

**scope**

I bumped into this issue on Stack Overflow, searching on meta displayed the same issue, so I think this affects all Stack Exchange sites (to be confirmed).

Comment: What is the point of using `deleted:no` with that intent if it's implicit anyway? If the logic is changed to your expected behavior, then, `deleted:no foo` will be the same as `foo`. At least the current behavior provides a shortcut to `deleted:no user:me`.

Comment: Search never includes deletes posts, except when bad caching is involved (which is an actual bug, the most recent instance of which has been fixed), but no operators are able to fix that. You do not need to use `deleted:no`, and it returning only your content in both cases is by design as an extension of searches never returning deleted content unless prompted

Comment: @Zoe As an aside, I'm assuming both `deleted:yes` and `deleted:no` work differently for mods (i.e., return results from all users). Is my assumption correct?

Comment: I bumped into an instance of [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400332/some-deleted-posts-show-up-in-search-results), which survived a few `Ctrl+R` on my part, but which indeed disappeared after a few minutes. So yes : you can disregard this issue as "not really useful" (at least for regular users).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine yep. But deleted posts still only appear when explicitly searched for. `deleted:no` is generally only useful when switching between deleted and undeleted often enough for typing the entire thing to be annoying

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "deleted:no" is not intended for regular usage