# Roomba'd questions are once again showing up in search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

This bug has [previously been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420161/6296561), but has once again regressed.

From the current [collapse burnination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcollapse%5d%20closed%3ayes):

> [image: Image showing four roomba'd questions show up in search]

There were a couple more, but I redeleted around 3 more of them before I stopped and remembered the bug had been fixed and this shouldn't happen.

Direct links to the questions (note; all have since been manually redeleted to better track burnination process. There are live examples after this list):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72558575/jquery-datatable-with-multilevel-grouping-and-expand-collapse-functionality
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60050417/return-expanded-results-for-one-document-in-solr
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629325/lack-of-easing-effect-when-collapsing-bootstrap-table-rows
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309664/bootstrap-nav-bar-collapse-dropdown-broke

All the posts in question were deleted on 2022-11-26 at roughly 1 in the morning (UTC), so these questions aren't questions missed by the manual cleanup when the bug had regressed.

I also found some that were deleted 27 days ago:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117229/how-to-learn-java-entreprises-edition-and-what-is-the-basic-for-learn
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114455/how-to-write-an-horizontal-infinite-scroll-timeline-like-plurk-by-javascript-or

Along with 7 more questions using a [very rudimentary search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-1+answers%3A0+lastactive%3A40d+closed%3Ayes&searchOn=3). Note that this is a poorly written query, and the `lastactive:40d` needs to have one day incremented to show the same 9 posts I saw on 2022-11-27. One day later, it shows 6 brand new questions, and with Stack Overflow's general volume, it shouldn't ever be empty.

Also found [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a..-1%20answers%3a0%20lastactive%3a..40d%20closed%3ayes%20locked%3ano&searchOn=1) after I realised I used the operator wrong which does find a total of 61 questions (and counting). Spot checks found a couple false positives, but the majority have roomba'd and shouldn't be in search.

There's probably more, and can probably be found with some more creative searches that better align with the exact roomba criteria (or different parts of the roomba criteria).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We found a piece in the re-indexing code that was pointing to our read-only DB instead of the main one T_T. This was causing a small number of posts to be desync when deleting the posts in main, but re-indexing from read-only.

We've patched the issue earlier this week, and today we force-ran Roomba again and checked, all new deleted posts where properly re-indexed as deleted.

As for older posts, we have a full re-index scheduled for next week that will cover them.

Thank you for reporting! Sorry about any inconveniences there.