# Roomba'd questions are appearing in search (again)

Tags: bug, status-review, automatic-deletion

This has now been [fixed twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421703/6296561). As of approximately 2023-04-10, the date some of the first questions were deleted, the bug has regressed.

[Demo search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=score%3a..-1%20answers%3a0%20lastactive%3a..40d%20closed%3ayes%20locked%3ano&searchOn=1); note that the search is inaccurate, and does include questions that don't meet the roomba criteria (or questions that do, but haven't quite roomba'd yet). It does, however, find plenty that have been roomba'd.

> [image: Screenshot of the question list showing three allegedly non-deleted questions]

All of these, with the exception of the "Model not assembled" one (which is due for deletion in 1 day, so it might incorrectly list later) have roomba'd, but still show up in search. Direct links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76002058/not-getting-old-data-in-time-series-widget
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975953/anaconda-login-failure-in-garuda-linux
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75983516/what-do-the-names-of-client-rules-mean

Additional samples randomly picked from the search:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75896145/can-someone-please-optimize-this-code-its-in-bluej
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895626/find-distance-from-camera-to-object-live-camera
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895407/need-to-convert-date-into-xml-gregorian-calender-without-affecting-the-format

Comment: *Roomba'd questions are appearing in search (again) (again) (again)*